swagger select a defintion for django
so, I've been working on my Django project Apis and i'm using drf-spectacular for the swagger view
this is in my settings.py:
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'Your Project API',
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Resume Swagger API',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,

}

and ofc this in my main urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    # Swagger Url
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
    # Optional UI:
    path('', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(), name='swagger-ui'), 
]

it has no drop down in order to select a definition, I mean i don't know if such thing exist for django:
this is how my swagger looks like:
enter image description here
but i've seen this for as far as i know for an ASP.NET project that has such drop down to navigate between different api endpoints as below:
enter image description here
is this achievable in django?
I've searched alot through docs and everything but i guess there is no such a guide to do this i hope someone comes up with a solution?
